# Как сделать счетчик перестановок и количества сравнений?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//функция, сливающая массивы
void Merge(int *A, int first, int last) {
  int middle, start, final, j;
  int *mas = new int[100];
  middle = (first + last) / 2;  //вычисление среднего элемента
  start = first;                //начало левой части
  final = middle + 1;           //начало правой части
  for (j = first; j <= last; j++)  //выполнять от начала до конца
    if ((start <= middle) && ((final > last) || (A[start] < A[final]))) {
      mas[j] = A[start];
      start++;
    } else {
      mas[j] = A[final];
      final++;
    }
  //возвращение результата в список
  for (j = first; j <= last; j++)
    A[j] = mas[j];
  delete[] mas;
};
//рекурсивная процедура сортировки
void MergeSort(int *A, int first, int last) {
  if (first < last) {
    MergeSort(A, first, (first + last) / 2);  //сортировка левой части
    MergeSort(A, (first + last) / 2 + 1, last);  //сортировка правой части
    Merge(A, first, last);  //слияние двух частей
  }
}
//главная функция
void main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
  int i, n;
  int *A = new int[100];
  cout << "Размер массива > ";
  cin >> n;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    cout << i << " элемент > ";
    cin >> A[i];
  }
  MergeSort(A, 1, n);  //вызов сортирующей процедуры
  cout << "Упорядоченный массив: ";  //вывод упорядоченного массива
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    cout << A[i] << " ";
  delete[] A;
  system("pause>>void");
}


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void quickSort(int a[], long N) {
    if (N < 2)
        return;
 
    long i = 0, j = N - 1;
    int p = a[N >> 1];
 
    while (i < j) {
        while (a[i] < p) i++;
        while (a[j] > p) j--;
 
        if (i < j)
            swap(a[i++], a[j--]);
    }
 
    quickSort(a, j);
    quickSort(a + i, N - i);
}
void funcprint(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <size; i++)
        cout<< arr[i]<<" " ;
    cout<<endl;
}
 
 
int main() {
    int a[10] = { 1,2,3,4,1,2,6,7,8 };
    int N = 8;
    quickSort(a, N);
    funcprint(a, N);
}
```

Comment: Проще всего сделать их глобальными переменными.

Comment: это как?и где их нужно ставить?

Comment: Основное в профессии программиста это принятие решений (**самостоятельное**). Попробуйте, может быть понравится. Если нет, то завязывайте с программированием, кроме мучений вы **ничего** тут не найдете